# Аналог питоновского requests session в node.js

Tags: node.js, юнит-тесты, сессия, test-automation

Когда приложение тестируется автоматизированно, а страницы требуют предварительной авторизации, то программисты на питоне могут использовать удобный объект, который сохранит куки при программной авторизации и дальше дёргать что душе угодно

Есть ли возможность, используя node.js для автоматизированных тестов - иметь нечто подобное, некий разделяемый между разными fetch "объект сессии" или придётся ручками считывать заголовок set-cookie и потом его проставлять в следующих fetch?